# Pandas Data Error on value_counts() does not display the count correctly to clean data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

When cleaning the data it is required to identify any typos
in the particular column that has to be cleaned the values are either 1 or 0 for denoting Yes or No.

To view the typos i try to `print(df["Column Name"].value_counts())`

The results come as

```
1     40
1     67
0     89
0     33
Y      3
```

I try the replace command for Y but it will then result adding 3 for one set of 1s and display only that 1 set and a single 0 set.

Why the same type are being categorised as two types ?
How is it possible to amend the string to the Numbers and get the following result as it should be

```
1     110
0     122
```

I tried

```
df["Column Name"].str.strip()
df["Column Name"].replace(" 1","1")
df["Column Name"].replace("Y","1")
```

Comment: What is the output of `df["Column Name"].unique()`?

Comment: I guess the data type is different.

Comment: ['1' '0' 'Y' 1 0] is the output of unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust method to convert your data might be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column Name': [0, 1, '1', '1 ', '  1 ', 'Y', 'N']})

mapper = {'Y': 1, 'N': 0}

df['out'] = df['Column Name'].astype(str).str.strip().replace(mapper)#.astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  Column Name out
0           0   0
1           1   1
2           1   1
3          1    1
4          1    1
5           Y   1
6           N   0
```

Comment: .astype(int) is required otherwise the code need to be executed twice. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['Column Name'] = pd.to_numeric(df["Column Name"].str.strip().replace({'Y': 1, 'N': 0}))
df.value_counts()
```

Try to use the `np.unique` to check your dataframe:

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(df['Column Name'], return_counts=True)
```

Without modification:

```
>>> df['Column Name'].value_counts(sort=False)
1     40
1     67
0     89
0     33
Y      3
Name: Column Name, dtype: int64
```

With modification:

```
>>> pd.to_numeric(df["Column Name"].str.strip().replace({'Y': 1, 'N': 0})).value_counts()
0    122
1    110
Name: Column Name, dtype: int64
```